# why addresses of two pointers are Contigious?

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    unsigned int * p,*q; 

    printf("%u,%u\n",&p,&q);    
    return 0;
}
```

Output of above code is `3218088104,3218088108`. As pointers have random address why are they contigious?

Comment: Pointers does not have random addresses.

Comment: Who says they have random addresses? *Edit*: damn, @nos, you beat me

Comment: You're confusing random addresses with garbage contents.

Answer (score 5):

You've allocated two objects that the compiler decided to place on the stack. They also happen to be next to each other on the stack. Therefore they have sequential addresses.

You can see the *values* of those two variables by doing:

```
printf("%p %p\n", (void *) p, (void *) q);
```

But those values aren't random, they're just *unspecified*.

***Other things to note:*** Using `%u` to print a value of type `unsigned int **` is undefined behavior. The correct code is to cast to `void *` and use the format specifier `%p`.

Comment: *Using %u to print a value of type unsigned int ** is undefined behavior* as is `%p` to print a `unsigned int *` value: you have to cast `p` and `q` to  `void *`.

Comment: @ouah: Blah. I forgot that again.

Comment: Afaik, reading the values (not the addresses) of uninitialized variables is UB in C90 and C11 (and should be treated as such in C99). The addresses of these variables are unspecified, but reading them is defined.

Comment: The compiler didn't decide, those are local variables that *belong* to the stack.

Comment: @PavelŠimerda: Can you show me where the C standard talks about the stack and heap even being a thing? A sufficiently advanced compiler could certainly push those variables to globals if it wanted to. Or just optimize them away all together.

Comment: @sharth: After you point me to a full featured C implementation not using a stack for local variables ;). It would indeed be a great compiler to share the state of local variables between calls.

Comment: @sharth: Stepping back with this specific case, though, as the `main()` function is only one and it could indeed by optimized in any way. Although it's an implementation detail and doesn't seem to have any value for the question being asked.

Answer (score 3):

You are outputting the *addresses* of the pointers, which are created back-to-back on the stack. If you remove the `&`s from the printf call you'll be printing the *values* of the pointers, which will be uninitialized stack space and could be anything.

Comment: Note: the compiler could put them in any order on the stack as well. There isn't a guarantee they are in the order of declaration

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps the confusion is in the fact that there is no guarantee of where in memory your program will be loaded, so even though they will be consecutive in memory, they may be at addresses 2686748 and 2686744 or 3218088104, 3218088108 or anywhere else. In this sense it could be considered "random". Though that is not the best way to think about it.

Comment: +1 for the first answer mentioning multiple meanings of *random*.